# Do rust and cargo 1.56 simply not work with Android NDK r23 (without binutils)?

Tags: android, rust, android-ndk, rust-cargo

I am not a heavy user of rust, so I don't know all of its customs and terminology.  I have a project that builds just fine (on a Linux x86_64 host) with Android NDK r21d with cargo, but when I use Android NDK r23b, it fails because binutils has been removed from the NDK:

```
  error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is `aarch64-linux-android-ar` installed?

$ rustc -V
rustc 1.56.1 (59eed8a2a 2021-11-01)
$ cargo -V
cargo 1.56.0 (4ed5d137b 2021-10-04)
```

I can find Github issues from many months ago for a few projects written in rust that encountered the same or similar problems caused by the removal of binutils.

Do the current versions of rust and cargo simply not support using LLVM's tools (such as `llvm-ar`) when compiling for Android?

Comment: Are you trying to compile or run on Android?

Comment: I am building on Linux x86_64.  I edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: Seems that way. I'd suggest raising a bug with rust.

Comment: Thanks @DanAlbert.  Let's see what happens: https://github.com/alexcrichton/cc-rs/issues/636

Answer (score 3):

Individual arch `*ar` binary has been removed from NDK 23+.

To fix copy and rename `llvm-ar` to `aarch64-linux-android-ar` in `${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/{SYSTEM}/bin`

OR

set this env var:

`AR_aarch64_linux_android=${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/{SYSTEM}/bin/llvm-ar`

Do these for all your target arch.